# Cannot type upper case E in VS Code and Python

Tags: visual-studio-code

I started using VS code for Python project recently, but I'm having a strange problem every time I try to type in uppercase E in my code.

Typing uppercase E always triggers the following popup in VS code,

[image]

I'm using all default of the VS code and its Python plugin (Microsoft) and only selected the Python version I want to use for the project.

This is the VS code I'm using:

[image]

Comment: Sure you are doing shift + e and not accidentally hitting ctrl + e ?

Comment: I don't know why I have the key-binding shift+e for enabling python linting; and it's a user setting! After removing this key-binding, it works as expected now.

Comment: That's weird! Maybe something the python plugin did automatically? Glad its working now :)